# S5 cm12.1 won't allow to transfer files to pc

Tags: custom-roms

This is very peculiar I have similar problems in the past but all were easy fixes. My s5 will charge when plugged into the computer but there is no other indication that the device is plugged. I've tried reinstalling drivers but still nothing. Looked into setting in developers options to take a look at the USB debugging but sadly it was greyed out and told me options weren't available in charging mode. Does anyone have any idea how to get it out I've tried everything I could want to flash back the stock ROM.

Edit: charger actually didn't support data transfers but it worked with the same charger before. Charger must be getting old

Comment: `setprop persist.sys.usb.config mtp,ptp,adb` from a root shell. I actually prefer set to `none` because it protects your data when the phone is stolen. (Assuming bootloader is locked)

Comment: thanks not saying cm is a bad rom but s5 is just terrible for custom  rom. little problems like these I have to solve every other day. gets aggrevating :p

Comment: S5 has a terrible camera too. Upgraded from Note 2 and glare is so much worse.

Comment: Did you try to change the cable you're using? Maybe the current one doesn't support data transfers.

Comment: With which CM build are we particularly dealing with? Is it a nightly or a stable one? If nightly, have you tried a stable build and see if the issue persist?

Comment: Yes I've trued with 2 different ones but I don't have the original charger that came with it. It has worked without the original though

Comment: and it is nightly but no I have not tried any other version. I'm just having a hard time tracing what the actual problem factor is